# Github action access token for user submitting PR that enables checking if user is member of team

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

I'm trying to add a CD deployment step to our Github Action. As part of that, I need a Github access token that has the ability to check if the user that submitted the PR is a member of a particular team.

`GITHUB_TOKEN` seems to the mechanism for getting that in a Github Action but it does not seem to have permission to access this API or isn't impersonating the user as when I use it in an action to try to test this approach:

```
      - name: Check team membership
        run: |
          curl \
            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" \
            https://api.github.com/orgs/fabriq-cloud/teams/fabriq/members
```

I get a 404:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/teams#list-team-members"
}
```

while locally with an PAT for the same user this returns the list of members of the team.

Is there a way to get an GITHUB_TOKEN that can has the ability to impersonate the user submitting the PR with a narrow scope to check if that user is the member of a team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret is basically a GitHub App installation access token and its [permissions are limited](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) to the repository that contains your workflow since the App has access to a single repo.

Try to generate a separate token (selecting the `read:org` scope), set up it as an [Actions Secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets) for your repo, and then use this new secret for accessing the Teams API in your Workflow.

`read:org` scope: Read-only access to organization membership, organization projects, and team membership.

**Additional references**:

- [Automatic token authentication official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication)
- [The GITHUB_TOKEN in GitHub Actions: How it Works, Change Permissions, Customizations (dev.to)](https://dev.to/github/the-githubtoken-in-github-actions-how-it-works-change-permissions-customizations-3cgp)